# CdbCriteria is not giving Join results

Tags: php, yii, criteria

When I am trying to fetch the results using CDbCriteria the It does not give me the expected results where as when I run the same query that is generated by CDbCriteria in the phpmyadmin then I get the results. I do not understand whats happening.

Criteria is as follows :-

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
       $criteria->select = 't.*c.*' ;
       $criteria->join = 'LEFT OUTER JOIN `flight_cancel` as `c` on t.ticket_id = c.ticket_id';
       $criteria->compare('t.booking_id', $bookingId);
       $data = FlightTicket::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Whereas the query is

```
    SELECT t.*c.* FROM `flight_ticket` `t` LEFT OUTER JOIN `flight_cancel` as `c` on
 t.ticket_id = c.ticket_id WHERE t.booking_id= 'something'
```

When Using CDbCriteria It only returns me the flight_ticket data and not the flight_cancel data.

What I am doing wrong ??

Comment: Does `flight_cancel` have an ActiveRecord class? If so, have you defined it as a relation for `FlightTicket`?

Comment: yes .. flight_cancel has an activerecord class and yes I have defined the relation too

Comment: your code `FlightTicket::model()->findAll($criteria);` will give you `FlightTicket` ActiveRecords

Comment: Yes.. So How could I fetch the related table records with it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$data = FlightTicket::model()->findAll($criteria);` will return only `FlightTicket` records. Since `flight_cancel` has an ActiveRecord class say `FlightCancel` and a relation `flightCancel` in `FlightTicket` you can alter your criteria to include this:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->together = true; // perform eager loading
$criteria->with = array('flightCancel' => array('joinType'=>'left outer join'));
$criteria->compare('t.booking_id', $bookingId);
$data = FlightTicket::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

You can then access your `FlightCancel` data through `$model->flightCancel` (or `$model->flightCancel[]` for a ONE-TO-MANY relation) where `$model` is a `FlightTicket` record.

**EDIT**

From the [yii database guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#performing-relational-query)

> AR relies on well defined primary keys of tables. If a table does not
>   have a primary key, it is required that the corresponding AR class
>   specify which column(s) should be the primary key by overriding the
>   primaryKey() method as follows,
>
> ```
> public function primaryKey()
> {
>     return 'id';
>     // For composite primary key, return an array like the following
>     // return array('pk1', 'pk2');
> }
> ```

Therefore without a primary key, you are better off using [`CDbCommand::queryAll()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand#queryAll-detail) to return the result of the query as an array of rows of the result.

Comment: The problem is that I do not have a primary key field in the flight_cancel table. So whenever I try to use with it throws me the error

Comment: I've updated the answer to reflect the lack of a primary key.